# how do I make a gradient background in Figma?

Tags: gradient, background, figma

I am trying to make a linear gradient backgroud accross my UI in Figma. How can I possibly go about this?

Comment: what have you tried? it works exactly as any other gradient. Also please check [ask], there's no need to repeat multiple times the same question. Please [edit] your question to add more details about your problem.

Answer (score 9):

1) You first create a rectangle of your choice color and then spread it all over the screen and then

2) Then select that rectangle and click on Fill option and then

3) And then from the drop-down at the upper left written Solid select it and change it to Linear for Linear Gradient and Radial for Radial Gradient and others according to your choice

4) And at last select the second color

And that's it

Hope it helped you!